# Continuous 404 even after redirection - what to do for mass

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

My WordPress blog's permalink was `/%postname%/`, but for some reasons I changed the permalink to `/%postid%/%postname%/`, and found there was much problem in many other cases, so reverted the permalink to `/%postname%/`, but within this time, google did what it was made for. And now I'm getting continuous 404 in many ways...

Common are:

- `http://example.com/%postid%/%postname%/`
- `http://example.com/date/%year%/%month%/`

So I installed Redirection plugin and using it for many days. I've made redirection for these two cause, but somehow it's not actually working. A new type of 404 is generating like

- `http://example.com/%postid%/%postname%/attachment-url`

I'm tired redirecting them everyday one-by-one from the above to:

- `http://example.com/%postname%/attachment-url`

What can I do now?
How can I let google crawler understand that I'm not in that instance, I'm back to my previous option?

Comment: Is `attachment-url` a literal text or some dynamic text?

Comment: `/%dynamic-attachment-url%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as your first rule after `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/([^/]+/[^/]+/?)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: it's a live site. I know you are knowledgeable about this types of issue, but would you please explain your code so that I can decide about it. And also please mention how to use this code? What's the `RewriteBase`, also?

Comment: You already have a .htaccess from wordpress and that has a line starting with `RewriteBase`. You need to place this rule just below that line. This rule matches `/%postid%/%postname%/%attachment-url%` and redirects those matched URLs to `/%postname%/%attachment-url%`

Comment: Oops! That made a 500 Internal Server Error. Here's my .htaccess: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mYIwL.png

Comment: I had a missing `)`, just fixed, can you try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let's see what google crawl next. :) Thank you.

Comment: With 301 in place Google will update its search results in due time.